# Android Suffix in edittext with gravity

Tags: android, android-canvas

Im trying to add a suffix to editText and used some libs, like these below:
[Suffix Lib](https://github.com/tobiasschuerg/android-prefix-suffix-edit-text)
[gist](https://gist.github.com/kennydude/5407963)

This is working pretty well, except if i give a gravity to my editText.
Im sure this is because textView position is wrong and i dont know how to calculate text position inside editText.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, here is part of the code to someone who need it

```
 val marginLeft = floor(layout.getLineLeft(0).toDouble())
 canvas.drawText(it, (textWidth + marginLeft).toFloat(), y2, textPaint)
```

After look where textview set position for a gravity center i found that it calulates layout getLineLeft and right